# openFileOutput not working

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm debugging step by step the following snippet and it doesn't create or read a file as its supposed to nor does throw any excpetion. This lives inside the main activity of my application. What is wrong with those lines of code?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
      outputStream.write("this is a text".getBytes());

      outputStream.close();

      FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput("test.txt");
      String string = new String();
      inputStream.read(string.getBytes());
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  String string = new String();
  inputStream.read(string.getBytes());
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It looks like you're trying to read data directly into a String.  You can't do that.  Strings are immutable in Java.  When you call getBytes() on a string, you are not getting its internal buffer, you are getting a copy of its data.

Instead, you should be reading into a whole new buffer until the the inputStream has not more data, covert that into a string, and display that.